# Matrix Representation of Wreath Product

Tags: group-theory

My aim is to understand the wreath product of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $S_3$ in terms of group of matrices. The problem I am facing is the following:

(1) In GAP, the wreath product of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $S_3$ is understood as: take $|S_3|=6$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and consider their direct product. On this direct product, $S_3$ acts as a regular permutation group of degree $6$. The resulting group $\mathbb{Z}/2\wr S_3$ has order $2^6.|S_3|=2^7.3$.

(2) There is a mathoverflow [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127447/wreath-product-and-matrix-presentation) with similar title. In the answer to this question, G. Robinson understood the  wreath product of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $S_3$ as: consider elementary abelian $2$-group of rank $3$, and let $S_3$ act on it by permutation group of degree $3$. The resulting semidirect product of $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^3$ by $S_3$ is the wreath product $\mathbb{Z}/2 \wr S_3$ (order of this group is $2^3.6=48$).

The wreath product considered by G. Robinson has nice interpretation as a group of integer matrices. But, how can we describe nicely the wreath product 
$\mathbb{Z}/2\wr S_3$ (as considered in GAP) as a group of integer matrices.

Comment: Are we talking about the computer algebra system GAP? If so, can you specify how you obtain a wreath product of order $2^7 \cdot 3$? This is possible, of course, but I would expect GAP to return a wreath product with three copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ if you do not tell it to do otherwise. Also, the order of the latter group is $48$, not $46$. ;)

Comment: @m_1: yes; type following commands: " >h:=CyclicGroup(2);;k:=SymmetricGroup(3);;g:=WreathProduct(h,k);;

Comment: @m_1: Sorry, there was a typing mistake in order $46$.

Comment: I did, and GAP gave me
`<group of size 48 with 3 generators>`.
That's why I'm confused. :)
This is the expected behaviour, by the way, since GAP represents $S_3$ as a permutation group on $3$ points (obviously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about the monomial representation of the wreath product of permutation group acting on copies of a cyclic group.

If $G$ is a permutation group on $m$ points, and $C$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then $C \wr G \cong C^m \rtimes G$ can be considered a matrix group $MW$ by considering $C$ as a group of $1\times 1$ matrices (the $n$th roots of unity) and then $MW = \{ a(g,c_1,\ldots,c_m) : g \in G, c_i \in C \}$ where the $(i,j)$th entry of $a(g,c_1,\ldots,c_m)$ is 0 unless $g(i) = j$ and is $c_i$ if $g(i) = j$.

In other words, the permutation is a permutation matrix describing where the nonzero entries are, and the $c_i$ describe what the nonzero entries are.

This can be done in GAP using the following commands:

```
`
gap> G := SymmetricGroup(3);;
gap> C := CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,2);;
gap> W := WreathProduct(C,G);;
gap> MG := Group( List( GeneratorsOfGroup( G ), perm ->
> PermutationMat( perm, NrMovedPoints(G) ) ) );;
gap> MC := Group( DiagonalMat( Concatenation( [ E(Size(C)) ],
> List( [2..NrMovedPoints(G)], i -> 1 ) ) ) );;
gap> MW := ClosureGroup( MG, MC );;
`
```

If you need more general $C$ (not just cyclic), then you need to use block monomial matrices. `InducedGModule` will do most of the work for you.

In order to make $W$ a permutation group (so that faster methods are available), you'll want to pass it permutation groups as arguments. `CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,2)` does this, but so does `SymmetricGroup(2)`.

If you really want the group of order $2^6 \cdot 6$, then change the first line to the following:

```
`
gap> G := Image(RegularActionHomomorphism(SymmetricGroup(3)));;
`
```

This writes $S_3$ as a permutation group on 6 points.

Comment: Let me know if this was a question about the theory (that isn't answered by listing the elements of MW). I just assumed you wanted GAP commands.

Comment: Well! The group of order $2^6.6$ you obtained in GAP is by first choosing the homomorphism from $S_3$ to $S_6$, and then wreath product w.r.t. the chosen homomorphism. This works in GAP, I checked. Now, I would like to see how this group of order $2^6.6$ can be looked up in nice way as group of integer matrices.

Comment: If you understand `MG`, then `MW` is the same group but where the 1s in the matrices can also be -1s. I describe them at the beginning of the edited answer.